# How to keep watch on a user portal to check for new notifications?

Tags: javascript, java, css, web

How can I keep watch on a website and if I get message or notification there an auto generated email will be forwarded to the specified email address ? the website like facebook but not facebook.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to know how to maintain a watch but not interested in knowing how to send emails.

You can poll using `setTimeout()` function of javascript where you can specify poll interval.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  if (somenotification) {
    //send email
  }
}, 1000); // polls at regular interval of 1000ms
```